# Есть предложения, чем открыть документ ?)

Tags: ms-word

```
    ����  JFIF     H H  �� <CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 75
 �� C
```

и далее 300 страниц, по пару строк нераспознаных символов. Кодировка выставленая при открытии файла - утф-8, в остальных предлагаемых кодировках проблемы начинались с первой строки

```
п»їusing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace РљСѓСЂСЃРѕРІР°СЏ
```

(Выбраная кодировка :винда - кирилица)

Файл 2013 года

Документ Microsoft Office Word 97 - 2003 (.doc)

Открывался в ворде 2007

При "востановлении текста из любого документа" (способ открытия в ворде) появилось куча нового, странного кода

```
c||"button"===c)&&b.type===a}}function oa(a){return ia(function(b){return b=+b,ia(function(c,d){var e,f=a([],c.length,b),g=f.length;while(g--)c[e=f[g]]&&(c[e]=!(d[e]=c[e]))})})}function pa(a){return a&&"undefined"!=typeof a.getElementsByTagName&&a}c=ga.support={},f=ga.isXML=function(a){var b=a&&(a.ownerDocument||a).documentElement;return b?"HTML"!==b.nodeName:!1},m=ga.setDocument=function(a){var b,e,g=a?a.ownerDocument||a:v;return g!==n&&9===g.nodeType&&g.documentElement?(n=g,o=g.documentElement,e=g.defaultView,e&&e!==e.top&&(e.addEventListener?e.addEventListener("unload",ea,!1):e.attachEvent&&e.attachEvent("onunload",ea)),p=!f(g),c.attributes=ja(function(a){return a.className="i",!a.getAttribute("className")}),c.getElementsByTagName=ja(function(a){return a.appendChild(g.createComment("")),!a.getElementsByTagName("*").length}),c.getElementsByClassName=$.test(g.getElementsByClassName),c.getById=ja(function(a){return o.appendChild(a).id=u,!g.getElementsByName||!g.getElementsByName(u).length}),c.getById?(d.find.ID=function(a,b){if("undefined"!=typeof b.getElementById&&p){var c=b.getElementById(a);return c&&c.parentNode?[c]:[]}},d.filter.ID=function(a){var b=a.replace(ca,da);return function(a){return a.getAttribute("id")===b}}):(delete d.find.ID,d.filter.ID=function(a){var b=a.replace(ca,da);return function(a){var c="undefined"!=typeof a.getAttributeNode&&a.getAttributeNode("id");return c&&c.value===b}}),d.find.TAG=c.getElementsByTagName?function(a,b){return"undefined"!=typeof b.getElementsByTagName?b.getElementsByTagName(a):c.qsa?b.querySelectorAll(a):void 0}:function(a,b){var c,d=[],e=0,f=b.getElementsByTagName(a);if("*"===a){while(c=f[e++])1===c.nodeType&&d.push(c);return d}return f},d.find.CLASS=c.getElementsByClassName&&function(a,b){return p?b.getElementsByClassName(a):void 0},r=[],q=[],(c.qsa=$.test(g.querySelectorAll))&&(ja(function(a){o.appendChild(a).innerHTML="<a id='"+u+"'></a><select id='"+u+"-\f]' msallowcapture=''><option selected=''></option></select>",a.querySelectorAll("[msallowcapture^='']").length&&q.push("[*^$]="+L+"*(?:''|\"\")"),a.querySelectorAll("[selected]").length||q.push("\\["+L+"*(?:value|"+K+")"),a.querySelectorAll("[id~="+u+"-]").length||q.push("~="),a.querySelectorAll(":checked").length||q.push(":checked"),a.querySelectorAll("a#"+u+"+*").length||q.push(".#.+[+~]")}),ja(function(a){var b=g.createElement("input");b.setAttribute("type","hidden"),a.appendChild(b).setAttribute("name","D"),a.querySelectorAll("[name=d]").length&&q.push("name"+L+"*[*^$|!~]?="),a.querySelectorAll(":enabled").length||q.push(":enabled",":disabled"),a.querySelectorAll("*,:x"),q.push(",.*:")})),(c.matchesSelector=$.test(s=o.matches||o.webkitMatchesSelector||o.mozMatchesSelector||o.oMatchesSelector||o.msMatchesSelector))&&ja(function(a){c.disconnectedMatch=s.call(a,"div"),s.call(a,"[s!='']:x"),r.push("!=",P)}),q=q.length&&new RegExp(q.join("|")),r=r.length&&new RegExp(r.join("|")),b=$.test(o.compareDocumentPosition),t=b||$.test(o.contains)?function(a,b){var c=9===a.nodeType?a.documentElement:a,d=b&&b.parentNode;return a===d||!(!d||1!==d.nodeType||!(c.contains?c.contains(d):a.compareDocumentPosition&&16&a.compareDocumentPosition(d)))}:function(a,b){if(b)while(b=b.parentNode)if(b===a)return!0;return!1},B=b?function(a,b){if(a===b)return l=!0,0;var d=!a.compareDocumentPosition-!b.compareDocumentPosition;return d?d:(d=(a.ownerDocument||a)===(b.ownerDocument||b)?a.compareDocumentPosition(b):1,1&d||!c.sortDetached&&b.compareDocumentPosition(a)===d?a===g||a.ownerDocument===v&&t(v,a)?-1:b===g||b.ownerDocument===v&&t(v,b)?1:k?J(k,a)-J(k,b):0:4&d?-1:1)}:function(a,b){if(a===b)return l=!0,0;var c,d=0,e=a.parentNode,f=b.parentNode,h=[a],i=[b];if(!e||!f)return a===g?-1:b===g?1:e?-1:f?1:k?J(k,a)-J(k,b):0;if(e===f)return la(a,b);c=a;while(c=c.parentNode)h.unshift(c);c=b;while(c=c.parentNode)i.unshift(c);while(h[d]===i[d])d++;return d?la(h[d],i[d]):h[d]===v?-1:i[d]===v?1:0},g):n},ga.matches=function(a,b){return ga(a,null,null,b)},ga.matchesSelector=function(a,b){if((a.ownerDocument||a)!==n&&m(a),b=b.replace(U,"='$1']"),!(!c.matchesSelector||!p||r&&r.test(b)||q&&q.test(b)))try{var d=s.call(a,b);if(d||c.disconnectedMatch||a.document&&11!==a.document.nodeType)return d}catch(e){}return ga(b,n,null,[a]).length>0},ga.contains=function(a,b){return(a.ownerDocument||a)!==n&&m(a),t(a,b)},ga.attr=function(a,b){(a.ownerDocument||a)!==n&&m(a);var e=d.attrHandle[b.toLowerCase()],f=e&&D.call(d.attrHandle,b.toLowerCase())?e(a,b,!p):void 0;return void 0!==f?f:c.attributes||!p?a.getAttribute(b):(f=a.getAttributeNode(b))&&f.specified?f.value:null},ga.error=function(a){throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+a)},ga.uniqueSort=function(a){var b,d=[],e=0,f=0;if(l=!c.detectDuplicates,k=!c.sortStable&&a.slice(0),a.sort(B),l){while(b=a[f++])b===a[f]&&(e=d.push(f));while(e--)a.splice(d[e],1)}return k=null,a},e=ga.getText=function(a){var b,c="",d=0,f=a.nodeType;if(f){if(1===f||9===f||11===f){if("string"==typeof a.textContent)return a.textContent;for(a=a.firstChild;a;a=a.nextSibling)c+=e(a)}else if(3===f||4===f)return a.nodeValue}else while(b=a[d++])c+=e(b);return c},d=ga.selectors={cacheLength:50,createPseudo:ia,match:X,attrHandle:{},find:{},relative:{">":{dir:"parentNode",first:!0}," ":{dir:"parentNode"},"+":{dir:"previousSibling",first:!0},"~":{dir:"previousSibling"}},preFilter:{ATTR:function(a){return a[1]=a[1].replace(ca,da),a[3]=(a[3]||a[4]||a[5]||"").replace(ca,da),"~="===a[2]&&(a[3]=" "+a[3]+" "),a.slice(0,4)},CHILD:function(a){return a[1]=a[1].toLowerCase(),"nth"===a[1].slice(0,3)?(a[3]||ga.error(a[0]),a[4]=+(a[4]?a[5]+(a[6]||1):2*("even"===a[3]||"odd"===a[3])),a[5]=+(a[7]+a[8]||"odd"===a[3])):a[3]&&ga.error(a[0]),a},PSEUDO:function(a){var b,c=!a[6]&&a[2];return X.CHILD.test(a[0])?null:(a[3]?a[2]=a[4]||a[5]||"":c&&V.test(c)&&(b=g(c,!0))&&(b=c.indexOf(")",c.length-b)-c.length)&&(a[0]=a[0].slice(0,b),a[2]=c.slice(0,b)),a.slice(0,3))}},filter:{TAG:function(a){var b=a.replace(ca,da).toLowerCase();return"*"===a?function(){return!0}:function(a){return a.nodeName&&a.nodeName.toLowerCase()===b}},CLASS:function(a){var b=y[a+" "];return b||(b=new RegExp("(^|"+L+")"+a+"("+L+"|$)"))&&y(a,function(a){return b.test("string"==typeof a.className&&a.className||"undefined"!=typeof a.getAttribute&&a.getAttribute("class")||"")})},ATTR:function(a,b,c){return function(d){var e=ga.attr(d,a);return null==e?"!="===b:b?(e+="","="===b?e===c:"!="===b?e!==c:"^="===b?c&&0===e.indexOf(c):"*="===b?c&&e.indexOf(c)>-1:"$="===b?c&&e.slice(-c.length)===c:"~="===b?(" "+e.replace(Q," ")+" ").indexOf(c)>-1:"|="===b?e===c||e.slice(0,c.length+1)===c+"-":!1):!0}},CHILD:function(a,b,c,d,e){var f="nth"!==a.slice(0,3),g="last"!==a.slice(-4),h="of-type"===b;return 1===d&&0===e?function(a){return!!a.parentNode}:function(b,c,i){var j,k,l,m,n,o,p=f!==g?"nextSibling":"previousSibling",q=b.parentNode,r=h&&b.nodeName.toLowerCase(),s=!i&&!h;if(q){if(f){while(p){l=b;while(l=l[p])if(h?l.nodeName.toLowerCase()===r:1===l.nodeType)return!1;o=p="only"===a&&!o&&"nextSibling"}return!0}if(o=[g?q.firstChild:q.lastChild],g&&s){k=q[u]||(q[u]={}),j=k[a]||[],n=j[0]===w&&j[1],m=j[0]===w&&j[2],l=n&&q.childNodes[n];while(l=++n&&l&&l[p]||(m=n=0)||o.pop())if(1===l.nodeType&&++m&&l===b){k[a]=[w,n,m];break}}else if(s&&(j=(b[u]||(b[u]={}))[a])&&j[0]===w)m=j[1];else while(l=++n&&l&&l[p]||(m=n=0)||o.pop())if((h?l.nodeName.toLowerCase()===r:1===l.nodeType)&&++m&&(s&&((l[u]||(l[u]={}))[a]=[w,m]),l===b))break;return m-=e,m===d||m%d===0&&m/d>=0}}},PSEUDO:function(a,b){var c,e=d.pseudos[a]||d.setFilters[a.toLowerCase()]||ga.error("unsupported pseudo: "+a);return e[u]?e(b):e.length>1?(c=[a,a,"",b],d.setFilters.hasOwnProperty(a.toLowerCase())?ia(function(a,c){var d,f=e(a,b),g=f.length;while(g--)d=J(a,f[g]),a[d]=!(c[d]=f[g])}):function(a){return e(a,0,c)}):e}},pseudos:{not:ia(function(a){var b=[],c=[],d=h(a.replace(R,"$1"));return d[u]?ia(function(a,b,c,e){var f,g=d(a,null,e,[]),h=a.length;while(h--)(f=g[h])&&(a[h]=!(b[h]=f))}):function(a,e,f){return b[0]=a,d(b,null,f,c),b[0]=null,!c.pop()}}),has:ia(function(a){return function(b){return ga(a,b).length>0}}),contains:ia(function(a){return a=a.replace(ca,da),function(b){return(b.textContent||b.innerText||e(b)).indexOf(a)>-1}}),lang:ia(function(a){return W.test(a||"")||ga.error("unsupported lang: "+a),a=a.replace(ca,da).toLowerCase(),function(b){var c;do if(c=p?b.lang:b.getAttribute("xml:lang")||b.getAttribute("lang"))return c=c.toLowerCase(),c===a||0===c.indexOf(a+"-");while((b=b.parentNode)&&1===b.nodeType);return!1}}),target:function(b){var c=a.location&&a.location.hash;return c&&c.slice(1)===b.id},root:function(a){return a===o},focus:function(a){return a===n.activeElement&&(!n.hasFocus||n.hasFocus())&&!!(a.type||a.href||~a.tabIndex)},enabled:function(a){return a.disabled===!1},disabled:function(a){return a.disabled===!0},checked:function(a){var b=a.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"input"===b&&!!a.checked||"option"===b&&!!a.selected},selected:function(a){return a.parentNode&&a.parentNode.selectedIndex,a.selected===!0},empty:function(a){for(a=a.firstChild;a;a=a.nextSibling)if(a.nodeType<6)return!1;return!0},parent:function(a){return!d.pseudos.empty(a)},header:function(a){return Z.test(a.nodeName)},input:function(a){return Y.test(a.nodeName)},button:function(a){var b=a.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"input"===b&&"button"===a.type||"button"===b},text:function(a){var b;return"input"===a.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&"text"===a.type&&(null==(b=a.getAttribute("type"))||"text"===b.toLowerCase())},first:oa(function(){return[0]}),last:oa(function(a,b){return[b-1]}),eq:oa(function(a,b,c){return[0>c?c+b:c]}),even:oa(function(a,b){for(var c=0;b>c;c+=2)a.push(c);return a}),odd:oa(function(a,b){for(var c=1;b>c;c+=2)a.push(c);return a}),lt:oa(function(a,b,c){for(var d=0>c?c+b:c;--d>=0;)a.push(d);return a}),gt:oa(function(a,b,c){for(var d=0>c?c+b:c;++d<b;)a.push(d);return a})}},d.pseudos.nth=d.pseudos.eq;for(b in{radio:!0,checkbox:!0,file:!0,password:!0,image:!0})d.pseudos[b]=ma(b);for(b in{submit:!0,reset:!0})d.pseudos[b]=na(b);function qa(){}qa.prototype=d.filters=d.pseudos,d.setFilters=new qa,g=ga.tokenize=function(a,b){var c,e,f,g,h,i,j,k=z[a+" "];if(k)return b?0:k.slice(0);h=a,i=[],j=d.preFilter;while(h){(!c||(e=S.exec(h)))&&(e&&(h=h.slice(e[0].length)||h),i.push(f=[])),c=!1,(e=T.exec(h))&&(c=e.shift(),f.push({value:c,type:e[0].replace(R," ")}),h=h.slice(c.length));for(g in d.filter)!(e=X[g].exec(h))||j[g]&&!(e=j[g](e))||(c=e.shift(),f.push({value:c,type:g,matches:e}),h=h.slice(c.length));if(!c)break}return b?h.length:h?ga.error(a):z(a,i).slice(0)};function ra(a){for(var b=0,c=a.length,d="";c>b;b++)d+=a[b].value;return d}function sa(a,b,c){var d=b.dir,e=c&&"parentNode"===d,f=x++;return b.first?function(b,c,f){while(b=b[d])
```

[image: Страшна (VS Code)]

Comment: namespace Курсовая, перед using ничего быть не должно было

Comment: Смени расширение на .JPG и открой любым графвьювером.

Comment: Просто напросто отказывают в открытии, гугл показал белый квадратик 10*10 ))

Comment: Тогда остаётся предположить, что файл давно и безнадёжно разрушен.

Comment: Видимо да )) Добавил ещё один скрин (VS Code)

Comment: Нет никакого смысла пытаться открывать бинарный файл как текстовый.

Comment: немного странное замечание, к чему оно ведет ? VS Code показал что есть много мест, что при стандартной кодировке считаються битыми

Comment: *Добавил ещё один скрин (VS Code)* Лучше было бы показать начало файла (хотя бы первые полкило) в каком-нибудь хекс-редакторе.

Comment: @Akina Нашел FFD8FFE0 прямо беред одним из "битых" кусков, как понимаю это картинка в аське =\ теперь вытаскивать их по одной ?)

Comment: @Akina теперь мне стыдно за человека, который в документ скопировал код с использованием маппинга изображений. За что.... Он ещё и сбился через семь лет то )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Akina, не знаю, может он спать ушел. Сами рассуждения в комментариях, а ответа лучше, подозреваю, не дадут. Особенно учитывая, что я не предоставлял исходник.
Следующее было выполнено при помощи приложения FlexHex и https://codepen.io/

1. Открываем файл сразу в FlexHex или подобном приложении.
   (без перекодировки в Ворде)
2. Вначале файла мы может увидеть шифровку файла - в моем случае она не указана
3. Переходим к сломанному куску. К счастью в этой программе есть столбик для просмотра текста(зеленый) в utf-8 и в нем видно анномалии, хотя не сказал бы что это удобно.
4. Копируем первые символы, шифр кодировки (FF D8 FF E0 в данном случае)
   [image: Элемент списка]
5. Ищем расшифровку в справочниках и получаем:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Копируем этот кусок до конца (поверьте, это долго)
7. Получаем подтверждение теории и вытаскиваем по картинке.
   В данном случае, результат с сайта (указанного выше) получаем следующий
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   **Честно - сам в шоке**, но код вокруг этих картинок стоит того что бы восстановить документ.